# YouTube Data API v3 Queries per day

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-api

Good day, I need your help, I use in one of my application YouTube data API v3, but I every day there is an excess of the quota limit (Queries per day = 1 000 000). Please tell me whether it is possible to increase the quota, even for money? And it turns out that the application almost half a day does not work.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7iBw.jpg)

Comment: Hi,I'm face the same issue,my app can't functions with the current quota, do you have any solution? did u get your extension ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a way to increase your quota but it's not easy. You have to go about filling up this [form](https://services.google.com/fb/forms/ytapiquotarequest/)

It will ask you a bunch of questions and information to reach you and then they will decide. It starts with this

> This Application will ask you detailed questions about:
>
> (i) your business,  (ii) your use of each YouTube API (current and
>   proposed use, as applicable), and  (iii) each of your website or
>   software application that uses or will use YouTube API(s) (each an
>   “API Client”).
>
> This application also requires you to submit screenshots and design
>   documents relating to your API Client(s) and your use of YouTube
>   API(s). If you do not have these ready, please apply once these are
>   available.
>
> We will strive to respond to your application as soon as possible,
>   provided that, all required supporting materials are submitted and
>   sufficient, and all questions are thoroughly answered.
>
> Note: Please do not apply for more quota unless you are actually close
>   to hitting your current limit.

Good luck with this

Comment: Ohh how hard it is(. Is it possible to connect additional quotas for a fee?

Comment: It's hard in the sense that you have to fill the form and then they determine. I haven't been through the process myself, so I don't know fully